# Computing $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

What is the result of  $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ . I tried to do couple of algebraic manipulations, but I didn't reach to any conclusion.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried writing this in polar coordinates so that you take the limits as $r$ goes to $0$?

Comment: Try to set $ y = x $ and $ y = -x \               $

Comment: What stef said, and/or $y=0$.

Comment: Generally speaking, the first two comments are fairly good approaches to problems like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $$x=r\cos\theta$$ $$y=r\sin\theta$$ then we have
$$\text{lim}_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{r\cos\theta+r\sin\theta}{r}
=\cos\theta+\sin\theta=\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4})$$
which depends on the angle of approach to the origin.