# How can I calculate $\lim_{(\alpha,\beta)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(\alpha,\beta)}{g(\alpha,\beta)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> What's the value of 
>   $$
> \lim_{(\alpha,\beta)\to(0,0)}\frac{[\lambda_i\alpha+\mu_i\beta+O(r^2)]
> [\lambda_j\alpha+\mu_j\beta+O(r^2)][-\lambda\alpha^2-\mu\beta^2+O(r^3)]}
> {\left(\sum_{i=1}^3\left(\lambda_i\alpha+\mu_i\beta+O(r^2)\right)^2\right)^{3/2}},\quad i,j = 1,2,3\tag{*}
> $$
>   where $\lambda_i,\mu_i,\lambda,\mu$ are constants, $r = \sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$?

---

I guess this limit may not exist, OR if it does exist, it should be $0$. For investigating the possibility, I tried some simpler case. For instance, let $\lambda_i=\mu_i=-\lambda=-\mu=1$ for $i=1,2,3$ and $O(r^3)=O(r^2)=0$. Then the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{(\alpha,\beta)\to(0,0)}\frac{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha^2+\beta^2)}{3^{3/2}(\alpha+\beta)^3}.
$$

> How should I deal with the term such as
>   $$
> \lim_{(\alpha,\beta)\to(0,0)}\frac{\alpha^4}{(\alpha+\beta)^3} ?
> $$
>   In general what's the value of (*)?

For the polynomial with only one variable, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0
$$
when the order of $f$ is higher than that of $g$.

> Do we have the same result for the multivariate polynomials which appears in the title?

Comment: If the limit exists, then approaching the origin on the line $\beta = 0$, for example, will give you the limit. This holds for any path to the origin, $\alpha=\beta$, $\alpha = 0$, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of the answer and comments to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101560/9464) question, I think the polar coordinates can help. Let 
$$\alpha=r\cos\theta,\quad\beta=r\sin\theta$$(*) can finally be reduced to 
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{f(r)}{g(r)}Q(\sin\theta,\cos\theta,r)
$$
where $Q$ is bounded, and $f,g$ are polynomials with respect to $r$.