# Behaviour of $\frac{x^{3} y}{x^{6} + y^{2}}$ around origin

Tags: limits, polynomials, multivariable-calculus

Lets study the limit

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3 y}{x^6 + y^2} $$

If we look at the limit along any straight line eg $y = mx$
we find that the limit tends to $0$.

Studying the limit closer we test for every curve $y = x^k$, where $k$ is some integer number. 
This gives that for every $k\neq 3$, the limit tends to $0$. If 
$k=3$, the limit tends to $1/2$.

Now this shows that no matter what straigt line, or curve (except $y=x^3$)
the limit tends to zero. I also tried a few other polynomials and they all tend to zero.

My assumption is the following:

> The limit 
>   $$ L = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3 y}{x^6 + y^2} $$
>   Is equal to zero if $y$ is any polynomial except $y = m x^3\,,\ x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is the claim true? If so can anyone help proving it?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/121779/9464

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. Take for example $y=x^3+x^4$. Then

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1+x}{2+2x+x^2}$$

and the limit along that curve will be $1/2$.

Comment: Indeed! But what curves then will tend to something different than $0$?

Comment: For curves $y=f(x)$, where $f(x)=ax^3+o(x^3)$, and $a\ne 0$, the limit is not equal to $0$. I do not know a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The set of limit points is exactly $[-\frac12,\frac12]$. In particular, the limit at $(0,0)$ does not exist.

Every value in $[-\frac12,\frac12]$ is a limit point since, for every fixed $a$, $f(x,ax^3)=\frac{a}{a^2+1}$ for every nonzero $x$.

On the other hand, for every $(x,y)$, $2|x^3y|\leqslant x^6+y^2$ hence $|f(x,y)|\leqslant\frac12$ for every $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$.